# setOnNavigatorEvent callback not fired when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am working on an app powered by `react-native@0.55.4` and `react-native-navigation@1.1.474`.

Initially, there is only a login screen (using `Navigation.startSingleScreenApp`). When the user logs in I call `Navigation.startTabBasedApp` (one of the tab components is my `NavScreen`). Whenever the user changes to another tab the root of the tab's stack is supposed to be displayed so I tried something like this:

```
class NavScreen extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.toRootOnTabSelect.bind(this))
    }

    toRootOnTabSelect(event) {
        const {id} = event
        if (["bottomTabSelected", "bottomTabReselected"].includes(id)) {
            this.props.navigator.popToRoot({
                animated: true,
                animationType: "fade",
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <Text>Whatever...</Text>
    }
}
```

But for some reason my `toRootOnTabSelect` event handler method is not being called when I change tabs (by clicking on them - not by calling the `switchToTab` API method).

There are multiple posts I found online (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51159091/6928824, https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/648) that indicate that it should work so I don't know what I'm missing. :/

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `react-native-navigation@^1.1.474` (note the caret): see [my issue on GitHub](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3599).

An [according pull request](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/pull/3808) has been opened but not yet merged. :(

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that can cause that is using `setOnNavigatorEvent` in conjuction with `addOnNavigatorEvent`, if you have a screen wrapper component that implement `addOnNavigatorEvent` your current listener will not work.

As mentioned in [documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=setonnavigatoreventcallback)

> `setOnNavigatorEvent` Can not be used in conjuction with `addOnNavigatorEvent`

Also

> Bear in mind that you can't use both `addOnNavigatorEvent` and `setOnNavigatorEvent`. `addOnNavigatorEvent` returns a function, that once called will remove the registered handler.

I would suggest trying `addOnNavigatorEvent` instead of `setOnNavigatorEvent`

Comment: I tried using `addOnNavigatorEvent ` but that didn't change anything in my case. I also searched through my code and didn't find `addOnNavigatorEvent` anywhere else so using both shouldn't be the problem. I also commented out all other occurrences of `setOnNavigatorEvent ` to make sure it isn't called twice on the same navigator instance but that also didn't help :(